# oracle-sqldeveloper mouse mapping issue

Tags: mapping, mouse, oracle-sqldeveloper

I found several articles describing the same issue i have, but didn't find a solution.

Since several versions of sqldeveloper(3.1-newest one, 4 i upgraded today) i experience mouse mapping issues. I tried rebooting, reinstalling sqldeveloper, and also after a reinstall of the operating system, nothing changed. JDK 1.7, but also used 1.6 before when experiencing the same problem.

When i want to select something from the menubar/any dropdownmenu, i have to point my mouse several centimeters lower to mark a menuitem.

I have a linux mint system. I would be very thankful for any help.

Thanks
Nico

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the related bug. 
Workaround: maximize window and reduce the size afterwards again.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/777425

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I would share my findings on a similar issues in case anyone else drops in here looking for more answers.

I have had a similar issue where the mouse pointer/clicker stopped working. I was working through a VPN and it was only not working while using SQL Developer. I figured it had something to do with the integration and that I'd restart my machine when I got to work. However, after researching the issue I still couldn't find the solution.

Finally I was about to restart the machine and I used Alt F to get to the file menu. Jumped over to preferences just to look at the keyboard shortcuts real quick. I couldn't scroll down to see them so I was about to give up and I happen to click the middle mouse scroll wheel down and everything started working again. :D

Comment: its realla weird whats going on with sql developer ;)  Not having this issue on my windows machine

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems I think, sqldeveloper does not respond to (most)mouse actions.
Java(TM) Platform   1.6.0_26
Oracle IDE  3.0.04.34
Versioning Support  3.0.04.34
the issue went away when I switched mouse to a clickable wheel mouse and pressed the wheel. the mouse causing problems did have a wheel but it was not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue where it was selecting the individual items while hovering with the mouse but left-right click was not working.

I hit the Scroll Button once and after that everything worked as expected.